# How do I give a base class a property or method that returns different types in the concrete class?

Tags: c#, object-oriented, object-oriented-design

I have a base class called `FieldBase` and I want to inherit from it to have different types like `TextField` and `NumberField`. I have a property Called `Value` which for the `TextField` is String and for the `NumberField` is Integer. Now I want to access the Value property in the base class and do some checks, but I cannot because I have to add the field in the base class.

Ideally, I would have added it like this:

```
public abstract class FieldBase
{
  internal abstract object? Value { get; }
}

public class NumberField:FieldBase
{
  internal override int? Value { get; }
}

public class TextField:FieldBase
{
  internal override string? Value { get; }
}
```

But as you know the compiler would nag and say you cannot change the return type when overriding. So the best way I could have come up with was like this.

```
public abstract class FieldBase
{
  internal abstract object? GetValue()
}

public class NumberField:FieldBase
{
  internal override int? Value { get; }
  internal override object? GetValue()
  {
     return Value;
  }
}

public class TextField:FieldBase
{
  internal override string? Value { get; }
  internal override object? GetValue()
  {
     return Value;
  }
}
```

Which works but sucks because I have to repeat the same code in all the concrete classes and looks ugly. Any better ideas?

Comment: It might be useful to also show the code snippets where `GetValue` is called. Staticly what is the type of the objects that is called on?

Comment: Tell, don't ask.   Use a `void` method to do all of what you want in accessing the fields, validating, and etc..  Override as needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You Can't. Why? because

```
var list = new List<FieldBase>();
list.Add(new  NumberField());
list.Add(new  TextField());

foreach(var i in list)
{
    Math.Sign(i.Value); //type checking cannot succeed, we don't know its its an int or a string
}
```

Generics don't really help either. Behind the scenes they make two classes each with the defined type, so you cant put them in the same list.

What you can do is move whatever code you are running against each object into a method on that object. ie

```
foreach(var i in list)
{
    if(!i.IsValid())
    {
       Console.Write(i.ValidationErrorMessage);
    }
}
```

now I can have:

```
public abstract class FieldBase
{
  internal abstract bool IsValid();
}
public class NumberField:FieldBase
{
  private int? value { get; set;}
  internal abstract bool IsValid()
  {
      if(this.value > 10) { ....}
  }
}

public class TextField:FieldBase
{
  private string? value { get; set;}
  internal abstract bool IsValid()
  {
      if(this.value.Contains("badword") { ....}
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

That's what *parametric polymorphism* (sometimes called *generics*) is for:

```csharp
public abstract class FieldBase<T>
{
    internal abstract T? Value { get; }
}

public class NumberField : FieldBase<int?>
{
    internal override int? Value { get; }
}

public class TextField : FieldBase<string?>
{
    internal override string? Value { get; }
}
```

Comment: not super helpful if you want a list of all fields though

Comment: My suggestion fulfills all requirements specified in the question. The OP did not mention anything about lists. Sure, we can imagine lots of requirements the OP doesn't have that may or may not invalidate a solution, but what's the point of that? Also, the problem can be trivially solved by using an `HList` instead.

Comment: i mean you have no base class where you don't specify the type. how is it better than no base class at all?

Comment: @Ewan It could be useful if the base class also provides behavior that doesn't itself depend on the type parameter (e.g. like C#'s generic containers), or if you just need a generic bundle of properties that carry certain application-specific semantics (something like a tuple, but with named members).

Answer (score 2):

**The OOP way** is to ask questions instead of asking for data.

```
public abstract class FieldBase
{
    public bool CanIHazBurger() => Clock.IsLunchTime && HasBurger();
    protected abstract bool HasBurger();
}

public class IntegerField : FieldBase
{
    public int Value { get; protected set; }
    protected override bool HasBurger() => Value == 42;
}
```